# woocommerce changing stock status text

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce website. I sell fabric. How can I change the stock status text?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3YO4.jpg)

I checked the stock settings but couldn't find it. Also, I couldn't see the plugin like this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_get_stock_html', 'woocommerce_get_stock_html_mod', 10, 2);
function woocommerce_get_stock_html_mod($html, $product){
    return $html;
}
```

https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_stock_html/

Comment: I don't understand exactly what I need to write so that I can write "meter" instead of "piece".

Comment: This is a filter for stock text what you asked. youhave message and entire product object. You can expand finction using your own conditioning depending on product object data. This goes in to functions.php

Answer (score 0):

add_filter('woocommerce_get_stock_html', 'custom_get_stock_html', 10, 2);

function custom_get_stock_html($html, $product) {
$availability = $product->get_availability();

```
if (!empty($availability['availability'])) {
    ob_start();

    // Burada stok durumu için kullanılan template dosyasını kontrol ediyoruz
    wc_get_template(
        'single-product/stock.php',
        array(
            'product'      => $product,
            'class'        => $availability['class'],
            'availability' => $availability['availability'],
        )
    );

    // Template dosyasında 'Adet kaldı' metnini 'Metre kaldı' olarak değiştiriyoruz
    $html = str_replace('adet kaldı', 'metre kaldı', ob_get_clean());
}

return $html;
```

}